# How to make promise to wait for all objects to be complete and then push to array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, web-scraping

The getURL() function creates an array of scraped URLs from the original URL. getSubURL() then loops through that array and scrapes all of those pages' URLs. Currently, this code outputs just fine to the console, but I don't know how to wait for my data to resolve so I can push all gathered data to a single array. Currently, when I try and return sites and then push to array, it only pushes the last value. I believe it's a promise.all(map) situation, but I don't know how to write one correctly without getting an error. Ideally, my completed scrape could be called in another function. Please take a look if you can

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

let URL = 'https://toscrape.com';

const getURLS = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(URL);
    const data = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const urlQueue = [];

    $("a[href^='http']").each((i, elem) => {
      const link = $(elem).attr('href');
      if (urlQueue.indexOf(link) === -1) {
        urlQueue.push(link);
      }
    });
    return urlQueue;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
  }
};

const getSubURLs = async () => {
  let urls = await getURLS();

  try {
    //loop through each url in array
    for (const url of urls) {
      //fetch all html from the current url
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      const data = res.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);

      //create object and push that url into that object 
      let sites = {};
      sites.url = url;
      let links = [];
      //scrape all links and save in links array
      $("a[href^='/']").each((i, elem) => {
        const link = $(elem).attr('href');
        if (links.indexOf(link) === -1) {
          links.push(link);
        }
        //save scraped data in object
        sites.links = links;
      });
      // returns list of {url:'url', links:[link1,link2,link3]}
      console.log(sites);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is a Promise related issue at heart.

You'll need to collect your `sites` into an array that is initialized outside the loop. Then when `getSubURLs()` resolves, it will resolve to your array:

```js
const getSubURLs = async() => {
  let urls = await getURLS();
  let siteList = [];
  try {
    for (const url of urls) {
      //         :
      //         :
      //         :
      siteList.push(sites);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
  }
  return siteList; // array of objects
};

getSubURLs().then(console.log);
```